# PrivateRoute not redirecting in reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, react-router-dom, mern

I was building a website for developers following a Udemy course. It redirects users to the dashboard after they log in. I need to make the dashboard page private, so that only logged-in users can access it, therefore I put it in a private route. If a user signs out, I need to redirect the user to the sign in page using the privateroute function, however private route does not redirect it will stay on dashboard page, and when I type localhost://3000/dashboard I can access dashboard page without the user having to log in
I need your help to fix this
Thankyou in advance

**dashboard components**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Dashboard = props => {
  return <div>Dashboard</div>;
};

Dashboard.propTypes = {};

export default Dashboard;
```

**PrivateRoute components**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const PrivateRoute = ({
  component: Component,
  auth: { isAuthenticated, loading },
  ...rest
}) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      !isAuthenticated && !loading ? (
        <Redirect to='/login' />
      ) : (
        <Component {...props} />
      )
    }
  />
);

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar';
import Landing from './components/layout/Landing';
import Login from './components/auth/Login';
import Register from './components/auth/Register';
import Alert from './components/layout/Alert';

// Redux
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import { loadUser } from './actions/auth';
import setAuthToken from './utils/setAuthToken';
import Dashboard from './components/dashboard/Dashboard';
import PrivateRoute from './components/routing/PrivateRoute';

if (localStorage.token) {
  setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
}

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
  }, []);
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Fragment>
          <Navbar />
          <Route exact path='/' component={Landing} />
          <section className='container'>
            <Alert />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/register' component={Register} />
              <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
            </Switch>
          </section>
        </Fragment>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**auth.js **

```
import {
  REGISTER_SUCCESS,
  REGISTER_FAIL,
  USER_LOADED,
  AUTH_ERROR,
  LOGIN_FAIL,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  LOGOUT,
} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
  isAuthenticated: null,
  loading: true,
  user: null,
};
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case USER_LOADED:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        loading: false,
        user: payload,
      };
    case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      localStorage.setItem('token', payload.token);
      return {
        ...state,
        ...payload,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        loading: false,
      };

    case REGISTER_FAIL:
    case AUTH_ERROR:
    case LOGIN_FAIL:
    case LOGOUT:
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
      return {
        ...state,
        token: null,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        loading: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**package.json in client side**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

Comment: `loading` coud still be `true`, that would cause the PrivateRoute to still be shown. Can you check, that you are actually setting its value somewhere?

Comment: Agreed on the `loading` value. You might want to separate that from the logic to render the component or the redirect. In other words, don't take any action until loading is complete and you have confirmed the authentication status.

Comment: yes it was loading problem thankyou guys . when i  removed loading  value from the render it redirects to the login page.

Comment: @Tom yes .if the login fails i set the login value to false .updated my question you can check it out auth.js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a loading issue. The loading value does not change. The value remained true,
Therefore, I removed the loading check from the render. This worked.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({
  component: Component,
  auth: { isAuthenticated },
  ...rest
}) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      !isAuthenticated  ? (
        <Redirect to='/login' />
      ) : (
        <Component {...props} />
      )
    }
  />
);
```